# phpDoc class constants documentation

Tags: php, class, documentation, constants, phpdoc

How do I document class constants for phpDoc? I've read the manual but I can't find anything about them.

Comment: using `@var` is the right way to do it, see https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#722-var

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to write PHPDocs for constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706051/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-phpdocs-for-constants)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that you can use `@const`, though I can't find any English documentation.  There's a German example [here](http://www.phpdoc.de/kongress/constant.html).  It shows `define` statements rather than class constants, but IIRC the syntax is the same.

---

Nine years later, an edit...

It is clear now that the above is *bad* advice as `@const` has not appeared in the docs and it seems it will not.

Using `@var` seems to work, though I cannot see it explicitly specified anywhere.

Comment: Better review of the `@const` documentation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18446766/367456 - it also explains that no such thing exists.

Comment: Should use `@var` as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27772200/2053165

Comment: Yet another terrible selected answer... Is it possible to change the selected answer? I don't recall, but you should.. --> Guys, do not use `@const` as it is NOT valid, NOT correct, and NOT in the docs. One day it might not work, kind of like being "deprecated" but still works until they decide to pull the plug..

Comment: @Wade or you can edit, as I have done. That's how StackOverflow works. If you can find some authority for the use of `@var` or whatever the best solution is, please do add it to the answer.

Answer (score 31):

Constants only need a docblock that contains the description. No specific tag is necessary.  The code parser itself identifies constants and displays them as such in the generated documentation ([here's an example](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/Parsers/_phpDocumentor---TutorialHighlightParser.inc.html#sec-constants)).

Comment: This seems to work for [phpDocumentor](http://phpdoc.org/), but to tell Netbeans which description to show in auto-completing, one must add the `@const` as described in the other answer.

Comment: It is `@var`, since `@const` does not exist: https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The full list of all PHPDoc 3 tags: [Tag reference](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/index.html)

The manual [says](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) the following:

> **@var**
>
> You may use the **@var** tag to document the Type of the following
> Structural Elements:
>
> - Constants, both class and global scope
> - Properties
> - Variables, both global and local scope