# Documenting constants with PHP documentor

Tags: php, documentation, constants, phpdoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [phpDoc class constants documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892063/phpdoc-class-constants-documentation)

I have defined several constants in my project configuration file. The constants are all well commented within the file, but phpdocumentor is not showing the description i gave to eachone. I wonder which is the correct way to make my description of the constant appear in the documentation. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * PROGRAM CONSTANTS
 * 
**/
// The directories will be stored as constants
/**
 *  PROGRAMHOME_DIR holds the absolute path to the home directory
**/
define( 'PROGRAMHOME_DIR', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . str_replace( array( '/', '\\' ), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $base_dir ) );
/**
 * PROGRAMIMAGES_DIR holds the absolute path to the images directory
**/
define( 'PROGRAMIMAGES_DIR', PROGRAMHOME_DIR . str_replace( array( '/', '\\' ), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $images_dir ) );
/**
 * PROGRAMLANG_DIR holds the absolute path to the languages directory
**/
define( 'PROGRAMLANG_DIR', PROGRAMHOME_DIR . str_replace( array( '/', '\\' ), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $lang_dir ) );
/**
 * PROGRAMPHP_DIR holds the absolute path to the php directory
**/
define( 'PROGRAMPHP_DIR', PROGRAMHOME_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php' );
/**
 * PROGRAMCLASS_DIR holds the absolute path to the class directory
**/
define( 'PROGRAMCLASS_DIR', PROGRAMHOME_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'class' );
/**
 * PROGRAMREMOTE_URL holds the remote URL to the program
**/
define( 'PROGRAMREMOTE_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . str_replace( array( '/', '\\' ), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $base_dir ) );
```

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [phpdoc for constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6706051/561731)

Comment: Well, those threads might seem like duplicates, but i actually checked them and are not. The issue with my question is that i want the constant description to appear in my documentation. Neither of those 3 clarify how to do that, that's why i am asking this in a different way. Plus, the selected answer as the right answer is not correct, because phpDocumentor doesn't support the `@const` tag.